# DDEV: Sequelpro throws an "unrecognized selector" error when I open it with the ddev sequelpro command

Tags: sequelpro, ddev

Ever since I changed my ddev config to use `mysql_version: "8.0"` the `ddev sequelpro` command opens sequelpro but I get an `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000329640` error after sequelpro opens. Is there a known solution to this problem?

Comment: There is an issue with Sequel Pro and MySQL version 8. You may need to downgrade your MySQL version. For example `brew install mysql@5.7`. More details here: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-revert-from-mysql-8-0-11-to-a-specific-older-version-such-as-5-7-21/2431/2

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the nightly build of sequelpro rather than the current "stable" release.
Simply use the `brew cask install sequel-pro-nightly` command on a mac or you could download the file from https://sequelpro.com/test-builds.